# Ran into a unique IF expression, looking for explanation

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am working through multiple different resources to learn JS. This particular one, Eloquent Javascript, is pretty tough, and I find a lot of explanations are minimal or are left for you to figure it out. Which is fine; I just move through it slower and ask a lot of questions on SO :P

Anyway, here is the full function:

```
function characterScript(code) {
  for (let script of SCRIPTS) {
    if (script.ranges.some(([from, to]) => {
      return code >= from && code < to;
    })) {
      return script;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(characterScript(121));
// → {name: "Latin", …}
```

I've worked through it but was reviewing tonight and realized I didn't completely understand the IF statement. My basic understanding of IF conditions is that:

```
if (true) {
do this
} else {
do that
```

But I don't understand how the if statement:

```
if (script.ranges.some(([from, to]) => {
      return code >= from && code < to;
    }))
```

is evaluating to true here. Here is a sample object reference:

```
var SCRIPTS = [
  {
    name: "Adlam",
    ranges: [[125184, 125259], [125264, 125274], [125278, 125280]],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 1987,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fula_alphabets#Adlam_alphabet"
  },
```

Thanks to everyone who has replied to my past questions and this great community in advance. By the way, I'm not confused about the destructuring of the ranges array (from, to).
Thanks again!
Jordan

Comment: Do you know what the `some` method does? See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for reference.

Comment: MDN is a good resource: [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: That helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after doing some reading, and letting things simmer in my brain for a day or so, I figured it out.

```
if (script.ranges.some(([from, to]) => {
      return code >= from && code < to;
    }))
```

There's two things going on here that had me confused:

a. The if statement doesn't end at

```
(script.ranges.some(([from, to])
```

-- the if statement INCLUDES the return statement below it. So it's saying, IF the ranges property in the script object returns code that is greater than or equal to from, and less than to, then return script.

Also, the return statement had me confused because of the arrow function. But arrow functions that aren't "concise", (not using {}), must use standard function return statements. The return statement isn't implicit if your expression isn't concise.
I wanted to post this answer here just in case anyone else was confused with this exercise like I was.
Jordan